# x86 assembly - how to identify register to register instructions

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, x86-16, capstone

I'm trying to identify all register to register instruction in a given dissasembled instruction list..

i'm using capstone as dissasembler engine.

after inspecting "Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual" i found that i need to look at the MOD bits in the MOD\RM byte, and if its 11b then the instruction is between two registers..

that worked fine until i came across the next instructions (in hex):

```
1) 81 EC 24 06 00 00 
2) 83 C4 30
```

according to capstone (http://www.cenigma.org/4AM3UGY):

```
1) sub  esp, 0x624
2) add  esp, 0x30
```

in the first instruction MOD\RM='EC' (11101100b) so MOD=11b
in the second instruction MOD\RM='C4' (11000100b) so again MOD=11b

and both are not register to register !

what am i missing ? is there more to it then simply the MOD bits ?

thanks !

Comment: In those instructions the MOD bits indicate that first operand is a register. The opcode indicates that the second operand is an immediate value. So, yes, your task is much more difficult than just decoding the MOD bits. Depending on what you consider "register to register" there also cases where the MOD/RM byte isn't used, like XCHG AX,BX, CBW, and SAHF. Then there's LEA AX,[BX] to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Intel's manual:

> If the instruction does not require a second [register/memory] operand, then the Reg/Opcode field may be used as an opcode extension. This use is represented by the sixth row in the tables (labeled “/digit (Opcode)”).

If we then look up `EC` from the first of your example instructions in the associated table, we see that it can correspond to the case where you're using `ESP/SP/AHMM4/XMM4` without any additional register/memory operand. In that case, there should be a `/5` in the instruction description.

And heading over to the description for `SUB` in the same manual, we see this:

```
81 /5 id   SUB r/m32, imm32
```

So what we've got here is a subtraction of a 32-bit immediate from a 32-bit register that is one of `ESP/SP/AHMM4/XMM4` (and of course, of those `ESP` is the only 32-bit register).

See *2.1.5  Addressing-Mode Encoding of ModR/M and SIB Bytes* in Intel's manual for further information.

Comment: thanks that explain alot, but how then can i determine if an instruction use two registers or less ? only by compering to all instructions in the manual ?

Comment: I don't know how you've structured your disassembler. But if we take `81` as an example: It can correspond to `ADD`, `AND`, `SUB` and a few others. But all of them have the operand combination `r/m32, imm32` (or r/m16, imm16`). Whether it's an `ADD` or an `AND` or any of the other possibilities depends on the value of the ModR/M byte. So you need to encode that information into your disassembler somehow.

Comment: Put differently: your disassembler would need to know that there's no `81 /r`, so `81 EC` would have to correspond to `81 /5`, and `81 /5` is `SUB r/m32, imm32`.

Comment: @doroninou You have to fully decode the opcode bytes, and then *if necessary* appropriately interpret the MOD/RM byte. Some opcodes don't use MOD/RM bytes but are "register to register", some opcodes use MOD/RM bytes but are never "register to register". There's no easy hack for this.